# If $X_n \overset{\text{a.s.}}{\to} \infty$ and $Y_n = O_P(1)$, does $X_n + Y_n \to \infty$ in probability or almost surely?

Tags: probability-theory, solution-verification, probability-limit-theorems

**Question**

Let $(X_n)$ and $(Y_n)$ be random variables on the probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal A, P)$.

Suppose $X_n \overset{\text{a.s.}}{\longrightarrow} \infty$ and $Y_n = O_P(1)$, i.e. $(Y_n)$ is tight. What do we then know about the behavior of $X_n + Y_n$ as $n \to \infty$ ?

I think that $X_n + Y_n \overset{P}{\longrightarrow} \infty$. (See my proof attempt below.)

I don't think that $X_n + Y_n \overset{\text{a.s.}}{\longrightarrow}\infty$ necessarily holds. (Although I don't have a counterexample.)

---

**Thoughts/Attempt**

*Claim:* $X_n + Y_n \overset{P}{\longrightarrow} \infty$, i.e. $P(X_n \geq c) \to 1$ for all $c \in \mathbb R$.

*Proof:*
Fix $c \in \mathbb R$ and $N \in \mathbb N$.
$$
\begin{aligned}
P(X_n + Y_n \geq c) =& P(X_n + Y_n \geq c \mid Y_n \in [-N, N]) \cdot P(Y_n \in [-N, N]) \\
&+ P(X_n + Y_n \geq c \mid Y_N \notin [-N, N]) \cdot P(Y_n \notin [-N, N]) \\
=& P(X_n + Y_n \geq c \mid Y_n \in [-N, N]) \cdot P(Y_n \in [-N, N])\\
\geq& P(X_n - N \geq c \mid Y_n \in [-N, N]) \cdot P(Y_n \in [-N, N]) \\
\geq& P(X_n \geq c + N \mid Y_n \in [-N, N]) \cdot P(Y_n \in [-N, N])
\end{aligned}
$$

Assuming w.l.o.g. $N$ is stufficiently large that $P(Y_n \in [-N, N]) >0$, it holds
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} P(X_n \geq c + N \mid Y_n \in [-N, N]) = 1,
$$
since $X_n \overset{\text{a.s.}}{\longrightarrow} \infty$.

By the tightness of $(Y_n)$,
$$
\lim_{N \to \infty} \liminf_{n \to \infty} P(Y_n \in [-N,N]) = 1.
$$
Hence,
$$
\liminf_{n \to \infty} P(X_n + Y_n \geq c) \geq \lim_{N \to \infty} \liminf_{n \to \infty} P(Y_n \in [-N,N]) = 1,
$$
so $\lim_{n \to \infty} P(X_n + Y_n \geq c) = 1. \quad \square$

---

**Update**

Here's a similar counterexample to d.k.o.'s below.

Set $X_n := n$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$.

Let $F$ be an arbitrary distribution function. Let $B_n \overset{\text{iid}}{\sim} \text{Bernoulli}(1/n)$ be a sequence of random variables that are independent of all the others. Let $Y \sim F$ independent of the other random variables.

Set
$$
Y_n = 
\begin{cases} 
Y, \quad &B_n = 0, \\
-n, \quad &B_n = 1,
\end{cases}
$$
for all $n \in \mathbb N$.

Then $Y_n \overset{d}{\longrightarrow} F$. In particular, $Y_n = O_P(1)$.

However,
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(X_n + Y_n = 0) \geq \sum_{n=1}^\infty 1/n = \infty.
$$
By the 2nd Borel-Cantelli lemma,
$$
P(X_n + Y_n = 0 \quad \text{i.o.}) = 1.
$$
In particular,
$$
X_n + Y_n \overset{\text{a.s.}}{\nrightarrow} \infty.
$$

Comment: What means $Y_n=O_P(1)$ ? That $Y_n\to 0$ in probability ?

Comment: $Y_n = O_P(1)$ means that the sequence $(Y_n)$ is tight, i.e. for all $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists a compact $K \in \mathcal B(\mathbb R)$ such that $P(X_n \in K) \geq 1 - \varepsilon$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$. (There are also other equivalent definitions of tightness.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $X_n=n$ and a sequence of independent r.v.s. $\{Y_n\}$ such that $\mathsf{P}(Y_n=0)=1-1/n$ and $\mathsf{P}(Y_n=-2n)=1/n$. Then,
$$
\sum_{n\ge 1}\mathsf{P}(X_n+Y_n<0)=\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{1}{n}=\infty.
$$
Thus, $\mathsf{P}(X_n+Y_n<0\text{ i.o.})=1$.

Comment: Thanks! For future reference for others: The last line follows from the 2nd Borel-Cantelli lemma and holds almost surely.

Comment: Do you by chance have a counterexample where $Y_n \overset{d}{\longrightarrow} F$ for some distribution $F$ ?

Comment: Oh, I just realized: In your example $Y_n \overset{d}{\longrightarrow} \delta_0$.

Comment: If you could take a quick look at my proof attempt to see if it looks alright, I'll accept your answer.

Comment: @zxmkn I think you may get rid of conditioning, i.e.,
\begin{align}
\mathsf{P}(X_n+Y_n<  c)&=\mathsf{P}(X_n+Y_n< c,Y_n\notin[-K,K])+\mathsf{P}(X_n+Y_n< c,Y_n\in [-K,K]) \\
&\le \mathsf{P}(Y_n\notin [-K,K])+\mathsf{P}(X_n< c+K).
\end{align}

Comment: Oh yeah, that's much nicer. Thanks! By the way, I added a counterexample based on yours to the question statement [as an update]. It works for any $Y_n \overset{d}{\to} F$ for an arbitrary distribution function $F$.